# Expo React Native - Android Keyboard closes immediately when tapping on input

Tags: reactjs, react-native, keyboard, expo, production

The Android keyboard "crashes" (or destroys itself when tapping on every input field)

Video of this bug:
https://i.gyazo.com/83f7eb2ce8541e2c8af749c719fd7fde.mp4

These are the logs:
[image: Logs of keyboard crashing/ destroying itself bug]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the versions of several packages.

Now using:

```
"expo": "~44.0.6",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.66.4",
```

**Edit 1-5-2022:**

Relevant package.json packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "expo": "~44.0.6",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1"
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "^0.6.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.4",
    "react-native-media-query": "^1.0.10",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.12.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-select": "^5.2.1",
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.35",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.66.5",
    "typescript": "~4.4.4"
  },
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, Anything else I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: @Vikaschhabra Could you share a bit more about your issue?

Comment: Whenever I tap on any text input in the app, keyboard opens up and closes immediately. Same like the video link you shared in the question @MisterJacket. But in my case it's happening only in build. 

I am using -> Expo eas build as the app is in expo, in expo classic build it's working fine.

Comment: @Vikaschhabra I am also using eas to build the app (to get a bundle for the playstore). I will edit my answer with more info on the packages.json.

Comment: thanks for providing the details, Let me check these.

Comment: Any luck? @Vikaschhabra

Comment: experience the same issue with preview build for android

Comment: @Hanif take a look at your package.json and compare it with mine. I can't tell which package(s) cause this issue though. For me it is working with the packages in the given answer.

Comment: @MisterJacket I have changed my package.json with yours and then I install them. But then I have warning on metro which tells me to use react-native 0.64.3 instead because this is the version expo supports. Also another issues with fetching data that I still didn't know what happen. But changing only react-native back to 0.64.3, leaving the rest with yours, removes the warning and issues, all works but the keyboard show/hide still persist after building it.

Comment: But does the keyboard work when you change the react-native version?